# Is there an R function used to debug the eval error?

Tags: r, function, desolve

```r
Lassa <- function (pars, Sh_0 = 10000, Eh_0 = 0, Iha_0 = 324, Ihs_0 = 81, Rh_0 = 10, Sr_0 = 1000, Er_0 = 0, Ir_0 = 100, Vs_0 = 1000, Va_0 = 100) {
  
   derivs <- function(time, y, pars) {
    with (as.list(c(pars, y)), {
      dSh <- p1 - lamh * Sh - m1 * Sh
      dEh <- lamh * Sh - (ps1 + m1) * Eh
      dIha <- n * ps1 * Eh - (zet1 + m1) * Iha
      dIhs <- (1-n) * ps1 * Eh - (delt + zet2 + m1) * Ihs
      dRh <- zet1 * Iha + zet2 * Ihs - m1 * Rh
      dSr <- p2 - lamr * Sr - (rh + m2) * Sr
      dEr <- lamr * Sr - (ps2 + rh + m2) * Er
      dIr <- ps2 * Er - (rh + m2) * Ir
      dVs <- ph1 * Iha + ph2 * Ihs + ph3 * Ir - (thet2 + thet3) * Vs
      dVa <- thet3 * Vs - thet2 * Va
      
      return(list(c(dSh, dEh, dIha, dIhs, dRh, dSr, dEr, dIr, dVs, dVa), logSh = log(Sh)))
    })
  }
  
  # initial conditions
    Nh <- with(as.list(pars), Sh+ Eh + Iha + Ihs + Rh)
    Nr <- with(as.list(pars), Sr+ Er + Ir)
    Kv <- with(as.list(pars), max(Vs,Va))
    lamh <- with(as.list(pars), (beth * Ir)/Nr + (beth * et1 * Ihs)/Nh + (beth * et2 * Iha)/Nh + (beth * et3 * Vs)/Kv + (beth * et4 * Va)/Kv)
    lamr <- with(as.list(pars), (betr * Ir)/Nr + (betr * x1 * Vs)/Kv)
    y <- c(Sh = Sh_0, Eh = Eh_0, Iha = Iha_0, Ihs = Ihs_0, Rh = Rh_0, Sr = Sr_0, Er = Er_0, Ir = Ir_0, Vs = Vs_0, Va = Va_0)
  
  times <- c(seq(0, 0.8, 0.1), seq(2, 60, 2))
  out <- ode(y = y, parms = pars, times = times, func = derivs)
  
  as.data.frame(out)
}

pars <- c(p1 = 0.497, p2 = 2.74, m1 = 0.0000497, m2 = 0.00274, ps1 = 0.0094, ps2 = 0.048, beth = 0.00017, betr = 0.004, rh = 0.0006, n = 0.8, zet1 = 0.0000476, zet2 = 0.0000323, delt = 0.0005, thet2 = 0.01868, thet3 = 0.00701, ph1 = 0.0667, ph2 = 0.0357, ph3 = 0.002569, x1 = 0.167, et1 = 0.94, et2 = 0.95, et3 = 0.9, et4 = 0.85)

out <- Lassa(pars = pars)
```

The previous algorithm is what I did. It was giving me the error message:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) :
object 'Sh' not found
```

I don't know who to handle this.

Comment: I would consider reformatting this question. It is super hard to read your code as is.

Comment: There is no Sh, Eh, Iha, Ihs and Rh in your pars vector, how would you want to calculate Nh ? Same for Nr, Kv, etc... You need to better identify what you want to do and what you are doing

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that `\`your text\`` is not really part of your code, and have edited it out. The readability of questions (both how you describe the problem and how it _looks_) is often important, I suggest you look briefly at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189, and keep the links handy when writing your next question: you only have one shot for everybody's first impression, and for many if it appears too jumbled, it will not be read and they rarely/never come back.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments. I am new in using R. I guess I will improve with practice.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-describing: you are attempting to reference the object `Sh` on 22 of your code block:

```
    Nh <- with(as.list(pars), Sh + Eh + Iha + Ihs + Rh)
```

yet it is not yet defined. My guess is that it should be initialized to the value of `Sh_0`. So I tried that and reran, and we get the same error for `Eh`. Then `Iha`. Then `Ihs`. See the pattern?

I don't see any real need to keep the `*_0` variables separate from the regular variables, so ... I removed the `_0` text from the two locations in your code block: the definition of `Lasso` and the definition of `y`. Here is a "diff" of the changes (full code far below):

```
--- 75335956.R.orig     2023-02-03 08:40:21.594773400 -0500
+++ 75335956.R  2023-02-03 08:40:29.224648800 -0500
@@ -2,3 +2,3 @@

-Lassa <- function (pars, Sh_0 = 10000, Eh_0 = 0, Iha_0 = 324, Ihs_0 = 81, Rh_0 = 10, Sr_0 = 1000, Er_0 = 0, Ir_0 = 100, Vs_0 = 1000, Va_0 = 100) {
+Lassa <- function (pars, Sh = 10000, Eh = 0, Iha = 324, Ihs = 81, Rh = 10, Sr = 1000, Er = 0, Ir = 100, Vs = 1000, Va = 100) {

@@ -27,3 +27,3 @@
     lamr <- with(as.list(pars), (betr * Ir)/Nr + (betr * x1 * Vs)/Kv)
-    y <- c(Sh = Sh_0, Eh = Eh_0, Iha = Iha_0, Ihs = Ihs_0, Rh = Rh_0, Sr = Sr_0, Er = Er_0, Ir = Ir_0, Vs = Vs_0, Va = Va_0)
+    y <- c(Sh = Sh, Eh = Eh, Iha = Iha, Ihs = Ihs, Rh = Rh, Sr = Sr, Er = Er, Ir = Ir, Vs = Vs, Va = Va)
```

and then it works.

```r
pars <- c(p1 = 0.497, p2 = 2.74, m1 = 0.0000497, m2 = 0.00274, ps1 = 0.0094, ps2 = 0.048, beth = 0.00017, betr = 0.004, rh = 0.0006, n = 0.8, zet1 = 0.0000476, zet2 = 0.0000323, delt = 0.0005, thet2 = 0.01868, thet3 = 0.00701, ph1 = 0.0667, ph2 = 0.0357, ph3 = 0.002569, x1 = 0.167, et1 = 0.94, et2 = 0.95, et3 = 0.9, et4 = 0.85)
out <- Lassa(pars = pars)
head(out, 3)
#   time        Sh        Eh      Iha      Ihs       Rh        Sr        Er        Ir        Vs       Va    logSh
# 1  0.0 10000.000 0.0000000 324.0000 81.00000 10.00000 1000.0000 0.0000000 100.00000 1000.0000 100.0000 9.210340
# 2  0.1  9999.811 0.1890803 323.9969 80.99530 10.00175  999.8369 0.1028912  99.96685  999.9070 100.5137 9.210321
# 3  0.2  9999.622 0.3779785 323.9940 80.99064 10.00351  999.6738 0.2052387  99.93421  999.8143 101.0264 9.210303
```

Over to you to verify the output is correct and as-expected. (I used `deSolve::ode` here. If you're using a different function/package, it's not clear in your question, but the change to `Lassa` should still work with your `ode`.)

---

```r
Lassa <- function (pars, Sh = 10000, Eh = 0, Iha = 324, Ihs = 81, Rh = 10, Sr = 1000, Er = 0, Ir = 100, Vs = 1000, Va = 100) {
  
   derivs <- function(time, y, pars) {
    with (as.list(c(pars, y)), {
      dSh <- p1 - lamh * Sh - m1 * Sh
      dEh <- lamh * Sh - (ps1 + m1) * Eh
      dIha <- n * ps1 * Eh - (zet1 + m1) * Iha
      dIhs <- (1-n) * ps1 * Eh - (delt + zet2 + m1) * Ihs
      dRh <- zet1 * Iha + zet2 * Ihs - m1 * Rh
      dSr <- p2 - lamr * Sr - (rh + m2) * Sr
      dEr <- lamr * Sr - (ps2 + rh + m2) * Er
      dIr <- ps2 * Er - (rh + m2) * Ir
      dVs <- ph1 * Iha + ph2 * Ihs + ph3 * Ir - (thet2 + thet3) * Vs
      dVa <- thet3 * Vs - thet2 * Va
      
      return(list(c(dSh, dEh, dIha, dIhs, dRh, dSr, dEr, dIr, dVs, dVa), logSh = log(Sh)))
    })
  }
  
  # initial conditions
    Nh <- with(as.list(pars), Sh+ Eh + Iha + Ihs + Rh)
    Nr <- with(as.list(pars), Sr+ Er + Ir)
    Kv <- with(as.list(pars), max(Vs,Va))
    lamh <- with(as.list(pars), (beth * Ir)/Nr + (beth * et1 * Ihs)/Nh + (beth * et2 * Iha)/Nh + (beth * et3 * Vs)/Kv + (beth * et4 * Va)/Kv)
    lamr <- with(as.list(pars), (betr * Ir)/Nr + (betr * x1 * Vs)/Kv)
    y <- c(Sh = Sh, Eh = Eh, Iha = Iha, Ihs = Ihs, Rh = Rh, Sr = Sr, Er = Er, Ir = Ir, Vs = Vs, Va = Va)
  
  times <- c(seq(0, 0.8, 0.1), seq(2, 60, 2))
  out <- ode(y = y, parms = pars, times = times, func = derivs)
  
  as.data.frame(out)
}
```

Comment: user21060315, does this resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. My issue was resolved. However, I'm still having a challenge in the model parameter fitting.

This is what I used on the same ODE:

Lassacost2 <- function(lpars)
  Lassacost(c(exp(lpars), n = 900))

Pars <- pars[1:23] * 2
Fit <- modFit(f = Lassacost2, p = Pars)
exp(coef(Fit))

I had the error message: "Error in lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) :
illegal input detected before taking any integration steps - see written message"

Can you please assist?

Comment: I have no idea, unfortunately. That's a completely different problem, though, so I suggest either you (a) accept this answer, then ask a new question, making sure it is reproducible (with sample data); or (b) edit your question up above to make it reproducible do that I can make the error happen as well.